# Generating all possible combinations of a timetable using an SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an awkward SQL Puzzle that has bested me.

I am trying to generate a list of possible configurations of student blocks so I can fit their course choices into a timetable. A list of possible qualifications and blocks for a student could be as the following:

```
Biology A
Biology C 
Biology D 
Biology E 

Chemistry B 
Chemistry C 
Chemistry D 
Chemistry E 
Chemistry F 

Computing D
Computing F 

Tutorial A 
Tutorial B 
Tutorial E
```

A possible solution of blocks for a student could be

```
Biology D
Chemistry C 
Computing F 
Tutorial E
```

How would I query the above dataset to produce all possible combinations of lessons and blocks for a student? I could then pare down the list removing the ones that clash and choose one that works. I estimate that in this instance there will be about 120 combinations in total.

I could imagine that it would be some kind of cross join. I have tried all sorts of solutions using window functions and cross apply etc but they have all had some kind of flaw. They all tend to get tripped up because each student has a different number of courses and each course has a different number of blocks.

Cheers for any help you can offer! I can paste in the gnarled mess of a query I have if necessary too!

Alex

Comment: What constitutes a block? What are the rules governing combinations? Do courses need to be scheduled in any particular order, like A before E etc?

Comment: Assuming Biology is a block and F is a qualification, should the qualifications be unique in the result?

Comment: @jpw - The courses do not need to be scheduled in order the block letters just need to be unique for each student.

Comment: @Lennart - Biology is the Qualification and F is the block. No two qualifications can share the same block. you could not have Biology D and Computing D.

Comment: do you have a course table and courseBlock table?  You'll need that instead of listing the course/block pairs in the same table

Comment: does course = lesson = qualification?

Comment: Yep, the courseBlock table exists. That is what I am generating the above list from. Course, lesson and qualification are the same in this context.

Comment: I'm not too bothered about clashes as I can remove them in a subsequent query. Its all about generating a collection of possible combinations. I know there must be some clever set based technique out there. I just can't see it!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @horse I'm using sqlserver 2012

Comment: @Alex, can you add create table statement and insert statements to the question?

Comment: @Everyone- thanks for the answers, the big clock has gone bong today. I'll check out all the suggestions tomorrow.

Comment: @Leonard- I'll stick something together tomorrow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a fixed number of qualifications, the answer is relatively simple - the `CROSS JOIN` option from the previous answers will work perfectly.

However, if the number of qualifications is unknown, or likely to change in the future, hard-coding four `CROSS JOIN` operations won't work. In this case, the answer gets more complicated.

For small numbers of rows, you could use a variation of [this answer on DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29666), which uses powers of two and bit comparisons to generate the combinations. However, this will be limited to a very small number of rows.

For larger numbers of rows, you can use a function to generate every combination of 'M' numbers from 'N' rows. You can then join this back to a `ROW_NUMBER` value computed on your source data to get the original row.

The function to generate the combinations *could* be written in TSQL, but it would make more sense to use SQLCLR if possible:

```cs
[SqlFunction(
    DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None,
    SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.None,
    IsDeterministic = true,
    IsPrecise = true,
    FillRowMethodName = "FillRow",
    TableDefinition = "CombinationId bigint, Value int"
)]
public static IEnumerable Combinations(SqlInt32 TotalCount, SqlInt32 ItemsToPick)
{
    if (TotalCount.IsNull || ItemsToPick.IsNull) yield break;

    int totalCount = TotalCount.Value;
    int itemsToPick = ItemsToPick.Value;
    if (0 >= totalCount || 0 >= itemsToPick) yield break;

    long combinationId = 1;
    var result = new int[itemsToPick];
    var stack = new Stack<int>();
    stack.Push(0);

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        int index = stack.Count - 1;
        int value = stack.Pop();

        while (value < totalCount)
        {
            result[index++] = value++;
            stack.Push(value);

            if (index == itemsToPick)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
                {
                    yield return new KeyValuePair<long, int>(
                        combinationId, result[i]);
                }

                combinationId++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void FillRow(object row, out long CombinationId, out int Value)
{
    var pair = (KeyValuePair<long, int>)row;
    CombinationId = pair.Key;
    Value = pair.Value;
}
```

(Based on [this function](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#C.23).)

Once the function is in place, generating the list of valid combinations is fairly easy:

```
DECLARE @Blocks TABLE 
(
    Qualification varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
    Block char(1) NOT NULL, 
    UNIQUE (Qualification, Block)
);

INSERT INTO @Blocks 
VALUES
    ('Biology', 'A'),
    ('Biology', 'C'), 
    ('Biology', 'D'), 
    ('Biology', 'E'),
    ('Chemistry', 'B'), 
    ('Chemistry', 'C'), 
    ('Chemistry', 'D'), 
    ('Chemistry', 'E'), 
    ('Chemistry', 'F'), 
    ('Computing', 'D'),
    ('Computing', 'F'), 
    ('Tutorial', 'A'), 
    ('Tutorial', 'B'), 
    ('Tutorial', 'E') 
;

DECLARE @Count int, @QualificationCount int;

SELECT
    @Count = Count(1),
    @QualificationCount = Count(DISTINCT Qualification)
FROM
    @Blocks
;

WITH cteNumberedBlocks As
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Qualification, Block) - 1 As RowNumber,
        Qualification,
        Block
    FROM
        @Blocks
),
cteAllCombinations As
(
    SELECT
        C.CombinationId,
        B.Qualification,
        B.Block
    FROM
        dbo.Combinations(@Count, @QualificationCount) As C
        INNER JOIN cteNumberedBlocks As B
        ON B.RowNumber = C.Value
),
cteMatchingCombinations As
(
    SELECT
        CombinationId
    FROM
        cteAllCombinations
    GROUP BY
        CombinationId
    HAVING
        Count(DISTINCT Qualification) = @QualificationCount
    And
        Count(DISTINCT Block) = @QualificationCount
)
SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY C.CombinationId) As CombinationNumber,
    C.Qualification,
    C.Block
FROM
    cteAllCombinations As C
    INNER JOIN cteMatchingCombinations As MC
    ON MC.CombinationId = C.CombinationId
ORDER BY
    CombinationNumber,
    Qualification
;
```

This query will generate a list of 172 rows representing the 43 valid combinations:

```
1  Biology    A
1  Chemistry  B
1  Computing  D
1  Tutorial   E

2  Biology    A
2  Chemistry  B
2  Computing  F
2  Tutorial   E
...
```

---

In case you need the TSQL version of the `Combinations` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Combinations
(
    @TotalCount int,
    @ItemsToPick int
)
Returns @Result TABLE
(
    CombinationId bigint NOT NULL,
    ItemNumber int NOT NULL,
    Unique (CombinationId, ItemNumber)
)
As
BEGIN
DECLARE @CombinationId bigint;
DECLARE @StackPointer int, @Index int, @Value int;
DECLARE @Stack TABLE 
( 
    ID int NOT NULL Primary Key,
    Value int NOT NULL
);
DECLARE @Temp TABLE
(
    ID int NOT NULL Primary Key,
    Value int NOT NULL Unique
);

    SET @CombinationId = 1;

    SET @StackPointer = 1;
    INSERT INTO @Stack (ID, Value) VALUES (1, 0);

    WHILE @StackPointer > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Index = @StackPointer - 1;
        DELETE FROM @Temp WHERE ID >= @Index;

        -- Pop:
        SELECT @Value = Value FROM @Stack WHERE ID = @StackPointer;
        DELETE FROM @Stack WHERE ID = @StackPointer;
        SET @StackPointer -= 1;

        WHILE @Value < @TotalCount
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Temp (ID, Value) VALUES (@Index, @Value);
            SET @Index += 1;
            SET @Value += 1;

            -- Push:
            SET @StackPointer += 1;
            INSERT INTO @Stack (ID, Value) VALUES (@StackPointer, @Value);

            If @Index = @ItemsToPick
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @Result (CombinationId, ItemNumber)
                SELECT @CombinationId, Value
                FROM @Temp;

                SET @CombinationId += 1;
                SET @Value = @TotalCount;
            END;
        END;
    END;

    Return;
END
```

It's virtually the same as the SQLCLR version, except for the fact that TSQL doesn't have stacks or arrays, so I've had to fake them with table variables.

Comment: This looks really good richard! I'll try implementing it now.

Comment: Awesome dude! That is a winner.

Answer (score 0):

One giant cross join?

```
select * from tablea,tableb,tablec,tabled
```

That will actually work for what you need, where tablea is the biology entries, b is chem, c is computing and d is tutorial.  You can specify the joins a bit better:

```
select * from tablea cross join tableb cross join tablec cross join tabled.
```

Technically both statement are the same...this is all cross join so the comma version above is simpler, in more complicated queries, you'll want to use the second statement so you can be very explicit as to where you are cross joining vs inner/left joins.

You can replace the 'table' entries with a select union statement to give the values you are looking for in query form:

```
select * from  
(select 'biology' as 'course','a' as 'class' union all  select 'biology','c'  union all select 'biology','d' union all select 'biology','e') a cross join
(select 'Chemistry' as 'course','b' as 'class' union all  select 'Chemistry','c'  union all select 'Chemistry','d' union all select 'Chemistry','e' union all select 'Chemistry','f') b cross join
(select 'Computing' as 'course','a' as 'class' union all  select 'Computing','c') c cross join
(select 'Tutorial ' as 'course','a' as 'class' union all  select 'Tutorial ','b'  union all select 'Tutorial ','e') d
```

There is your 120 results (4*5*3*2)

Answer (score 0):

Not really seeing the problem, but does this [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20ac7/4/0) work?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do with a simple union, however each select of the union would have a filter on only one class type so you don't get
BIO, BIO, BIO, BIO, BIO
BIO, CHEM, BIO, BIO, BIO
etc...

```
select
      b.course as BioCourse,
      c.course as ChemCourse,
      co.course as CompCourse,
      t.course as Tutorial
  from
      YourTable b,
      YourTable c,
      YourTable co,
      YourTable t
  where
          b.course like 'Biology%'
      AND c.course like 'Chemistry%'
      AND co.course like 'Computing%'
      AND t.course like 'Tutorial%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets use the paradigm where Table1 is Biology, Table2 is chemistry, Table3 is computing and Table4 is tutorial. Each table has 1 column and that is the possible blocks for that table or course. To get all possible combinations, we want to Cartesian Product all of the tables together and then filter the rows out that have duplicate letters.

Each column in the end result will represent their respective course. This means column 1 in the finished table will be the block letter for Biology which is Table1.

So the SQL for the answer would look something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1,Table2,Table3,Table4 
WHERE col1 != col2
AND col1 != col3
AND col1 != col4
AND col2 != col3
AND col2 != col4
AND col3 != col4;
```

Note: This is trivial to extend to the case where each table has 2 columns, the first is the subject and the 2nd is the block. Substitutions just need to be done in the where clause but if I ignore this case the code is much easier to follow along.

This is a little verbose but this works if each student must have a class from each of the tables and the max number of classes is 4 classes. This solution breaks down if a student doesnt have to have 4 classes.

The exact SQL needed may be a little different depending on what database your using. For example != could be <>.

Hope this helps!